# thymeleaf iterate over String to create img tags

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm trying to iterate over a list of Strings in Thymeleaf. I want to replace `${nombre}` variable for its value plus ".png", but for some reason just the atts title and alt are displaying the value. Could you please help me?

```html
<div class="modal-body" id="modal-champions-body">
    <div th:each="nombre : ${listaNamesChamps}" style="float:left;">
        <img src="../../img/champion_icons/${nombre}.png"
             th:attr="src=@{/img/champion_icons/${nombre}.png},title=${nombre},alt=${nombre}"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Result HTML**

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do either:

```
    <img th:attr="src=@{|/img/champion_icons/${nombre}.png|},title=${nombre},alt=${nombre}" />
```

or

```
<img th:attr="src=@{'/img/champion_icons/' + ${nombre} + '.png'},title=${nombre},alt=${nombre}" />
```

Answer (score 3):

If you will use every attribute with `th:` prefix it's also should be correct:

```
<img th:src="@{'/img/champion_icons/' + ${nombre} + '.png'}" 
     th:title="${nombre}" 
     th:alt="${nombre}" />
```

Link to [official tutorial](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#setting-value-to-specific-attributes) .